# Android Studio ShimmerFrameLayout preview not working correctly after v0.2.0 in Design View

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, shimmer

I'm using Facebook [ShimmerFrameLayout](https://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/) in my app. But It is not rendering correctly after upgrading from `v0.1.0` to `v0.5.0`. It is showing a gray color box instead of actual elements inside the layout. Does anyone know any reason for that and any possible fixes for this issue?

I have inserted the ShimmerFrameLayout to my layout file as below.

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:shimmer_duration="1000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/stat_container"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/stat_container"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/stat_container"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/stat_container">

    <include layout="@layout/placeholder_stat" />
</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

in **build.gradle** file;

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0@aar'
    ...
}
```

**Design View Preview with ShimmerFrameLayout v0.1.0**
[image: preview with v0.1.0]

**Design View Preview with ShimmerFrameLayout v0.5.0**
[image: preview with v0.5.0]